# Обработка емейлов

Tags: php

Как у емейла вырезать первую часть, которая до знака @.

Answer (score 1):

```
$email = "google.google@gmail.com";
$dog = mb_strpos($email,'@');
$login = mb_substr($email,0,$dog);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$partsmail=explode('@',$mail);
$partmail=$partsmail[0];
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$username = mb_substr($email,0,mb_strrpos($email,'@'));
```

И только так, так как символ собаки в имени пользователя НЕ запрещен, а распознавать экранирование - повеситесь. В доменной части собаки нет с гарантией, поэтому смотрим позицию ПОСЛЕДНЕЙ собаки.
А так, [@Shadow](/users/7771/shadow) прав.